# Change Number Format of x-axis Matplotbib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to change the number format in Matplotbib:

```
C_range=np.logspace(-8,3,20)
gamma_range=np.logspace(-6,2,20)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im=ax.imshow(
    scores,
    interpolation="nearest",
    cmap=plt.cm.viridis)
plt.xlabel("gamma")
plt.ylabel("C")
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.title("Mean Validation Score")
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(gamma_range)))
ax.set_xticklabels(gamma_range,rotation=45)

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(C_range)))
ax.set_yticklabels(C_range,rotation=45)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))


plt.show()
```

This gives the desired float format, however my values set by ax.set_xticklabels/ax.set_yticklabels are resetted.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Format the list of labels directly using list comprehension `ax.set_yticklabels([f"{x:.2f}" for x in C_range],rotation=45)`?

Comment: I now noticed that some values are very low. So, maybe instead `ax.set_yticklabels([f"{x:.2f}" if x>0.01 else f"{x:.2e}" for x in C_range],rotation=45)`?